# compiling C and fortran together in a eclipse project

Tags: c, eclipse, dll, fortran

I want to compile C and fortran and link them with gcc -lgfortran.
I have got this to work using command line and can write a script if needed but I want to know if I can use an eclipse C project where I can add both C and fortran files into the project.

The problem I am facing is that this project is not compiling fortran files (and thus not linking them). Can someone please help me in getting these fortran files compiled and linked ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. This is the answer.

Goto your C/C++ project properties.

C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor -> click on Select tools button.

Here add the GNU fortran compiler (or whichever compiler you are using).

Thats it !!!